# Grails unable to install uploadr plugin

Tags: grails, file-upload, grails-plugin

I am facing same error every time m trying to install uploadr plugin through "grails install-plugin uploadr" command , i have mapped `compile ":uploadr:0.8.2"` in the `BuildConfig.groovy` but then also getting this

```
error.![error][1]
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:uploadr:zip:0.8.2 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:uploadr:zip:0.8.2
```

The stacktrace output looks something like that:-

```
Caused by: 
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Proxy Authorization Required (407)     
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.handleStatus(HttpTransporter.java:458) 

    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:283)

    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:235)  

    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)

    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)    

    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)      


| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor  for org.grails.plugins:uploadr:zip:0.8.2  
| Error Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:uploadr:zip:0.8.2
```

Comment: What Grails version? Only declare it in the `BuildConfig.groovy`. Do not use `grails install-plugin`. Check your `application.properties` and remove the line with `uploadr` if present.

Comment: Grails version - 2.4.0

there is nothing like uploadr in application.properties.. But when m trying to use run-app command , again this error is coming.

Comment: Can your run `grails --stacktrace run-app` and add the output to your question?

Comment: I am not sure if the uploadr plugin is compatible to Grails 2.4.x yet

Comment: then which version of grails should i use.??

Comment: Well first provide the stack trace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working behind a HTTP proxy and Grails cannot access the internet. You need to

```
grails add-proxy My-Proxy --host=proxy-server --port=4300  // according to [this][1]
```

and then [activate](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html) the proxy configuration by

```
grails set-proxy My-Proxy
```